# C++ vector of class objects and dynamic memory allocation - part 2

Tags: c++, vector, constructor, erase

This is a follow up on my previous question posted here ([C++ vector of class objects and dynamic memory allocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65983681/c-vector-of-class-objects-and-dynamic-memory-allocation)).

`Someclass` is an oversimplified class for the sake of this example. Important to know that objects of this class are stored in a vector somewhere else.

`Buffer` is another class that has three types of members: regular variables (NAME), vectors (S), and pointers to dynamically allocated memory blocks (DATA).

If I comment `v.erase(v.begin()+1);` line then code compiles and runs fine. Bur `erase` produces a number of errors such as "use of deleted function `Buffer& Buffer::operator=(const Buffer&)`".

I think I understand the issue but do not know how to fix it. Would you please modify my example to make it work? Note, that the example is oversimplified and I need to keep these two classes and use of vectors.

Thank you.

```
using namespace std;

#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Someclass
{
public:
    int I;
    Someclass(int i) {I = i;};

private:
};

class Buffer
{
public:
    vector <Someclass> S;
    string NAME;
    float *DATA;

    Buffer(int length, string name) {DATA = (float*) calloc (length,sizeof(float)); NAME = name;};
    Buffer(const Buffer &buffer) = delete;
    Buffer(Buffer&& buffer) { 
        S = buffer.S;
        NAME = buffer.NAME;
        DATA = buffer.DATA;
        buffer.DATA = nullptr;
    }
    ~Buffer(){
        S.clear();
        if (DATA) free(DATA);
    };
    
private:
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    vector <Buffer> v;
    for (int i =0; i<10; i++)
    {
        cout<<i<<endl;
        v.push_back(Buffer(1000,"name"));

    }
    v.erase(v.begin()+1);
    v.clear();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use a `std::vector<float>` or `std::array<float,1000>` for `DATA` itself, and stop worrying about memory management at all?

Comment: because it is a simplified example, in a real case the class has many members, however, it is the vector member causes the issue.  "Note, that the example is oversimplified and I need to keep these two classes and use of vectors."

Comment: What's your specific issue with using `std::vector<T>` instead? You are aware that you can safely exchange the pointer to a contigously allocated array of `T` with any other API , which requires a raw pointer? This can be done using [`std::vector<T>::data()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data), and will work for any additional complexity. I don't understand your concerns, and there's really no need, to (re-)implement all that stuff for proper memory management yourself. Maybe you should ask (another) question regarding your issues faced with `std::vector<T>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of a simple reason. When you erase an entry, the array needs to remove that "bubble" (which is the empty slot) and compact the array. Which means that it needs to move some stuff. So when moving, what they do is something like this,

```cpp
// Form the MSVC xutility.h file.
for (; _First != _Last; ++_Dest, (void) ++_First) {
        *_Dest = _STD move(*_First);
    }
```

As you can see, the way they move it is by moving the individual entries. This means that you call the copy assign/ move assign operator of the object `Buffer`. But you haven't defined any assignment operators, but a move constructor. This tells the compiler that,

"Hey, this Buffer object only has a move constructor. Maybe the user just wants to construct the class by moving another. So it cant have any other assignments (both copy and move)"

So now the compiler doesn't generate them for you. This means that you now cant copy or move another `Buffer` to another (unless you move construct it). That's the reason for the error.

The solution is to add a move assign operator.

```cpp
Buffer& operator=(Buffer&& other)
{
    S = std::move(other.S);
    NAME = std::move(other.NAME);
    DATA = other.DATA;

    other.DATA = nullptr;   // Make sure to set it to nullptr.

    return *this;
}
```

Comment: And the solution presumably is to define a move assignment operator.

Comment: could you please show how to do it in this case, when the class has complex member types (vector, dynamic memory, etc..).

Comment: @SVS I added the solution.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your time and effort.  Do you think I should replace in the move constructor ``S = buffer.S;`` for ``S = std::move(other.S);``? And if i had a simple member say ``int i`` would I use ``i=other.i`` or ``i = std::move(other.i);`` in both constructors.

Comment: @SVS For complex types, use `std::move`. For primitive types you can use it but you can simply assign it and default its value. For move constructor, yes absolutely else you'll be just copying it.